Content Scripts Not Triggering on Specific Pages
I'm working on a Chrome extension where I need to inject content scripts on https:// www.ewccv.com /cvs/details. However, I'm encountering an issue where the content scripts aren't triggering as expected, despite what I believe are the correct URL match patterns in my manifest.json.
As you can see from my host_permissions and content_scripts properties, I've been testing what I think are all possible cases. Here are the relevant parts of my manifest.json:
"host_permissions": [
    "https://www.ewccv.com/*/*",
    "https://www.ewccv.com/*/search",
    "https://www.ewccv.com/*/details",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.ewccv.com/cvs/"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.ewccv.com/cvs/search"],
      "js": ["content1.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.ewccv.com/cvs/*"],
      "js": ["content3.js"]
    }
  ]


Behavior Observed:
On the landing page https:// www.ewccv.com/cvs/, content.js and content3.js work as expected.
On https:// www.ewccv.com/cvs/search, I expect content1.js and content3.js to trigger, but they don’t.
On https:// www.ewccv.com/cvs/details, I expect content3.js to trigger, but it does not.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with URL matching in the manifest.json? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

So it turns out the site is a SPA (Single-page application) as a result only parts of the site are updating which does not cause a DOM or window reload. I ended up using aspects of this stackoverflow.com/questions/66772626 and stackoverflow.com/questions/71935684 to come up with this
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener( async (details) =>  {
 const getCurrentTab = async () => {
     let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };     
     let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
     return tab;
   }
 let files = {"https://www.ewccv.com/cvs/details" : "content3.js"}
 let tab = await getCurrentTab();
 if (tab.url?.startsWith("chrome://")) return undefined;
 chrome.scripting.executeScript({
     target: {tabId: tab.id},
     files: [files[details.url] ?? "content.js"]
   });
});

So basically I found out that the event trigger listens for changes in the state of the browser's history that occur without a full page reload. This typically happens when a site changes the URL using pushState or replaceState methods of the History API. The event provides details about the navigation event, such as the URL that was navigated to, the tab ID where the event occurred, and other navigation details.
